# Natural language processing for Russian language

Tags: neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for library(es) or service(s), that can process natural Russian language:

1. Transforming words into initial form: "Они строили" => "они", "строить"
2. Recognise and extract combination of words: "Они строили железную дорогу" => "они", "строить", "железная дорога"
3. Not sure how to describe this: "Они не строили железную дорогу" => "они" "не строить", "железная дорога"
4. Interpret idioms or figures of speech: "ну и погодка" => "плохая погода"

Any suggestions? Libraries, services, sources of information - anything.

Comment: Might be useful to include for what programming language(s) the libraries should be :)

Comment: Language doesn't matter, i'll use the most suitable one for this case

Answer (score 2):

My goto for any natural language work is [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/) which in its own words is:

> NLTK is a leading platform for building Python programs to work with
>   human language data. It provides easy-to-use interfaces to over 50
>   corpora and lexical resources such as WordNet, along with a suite of
>   text processing libraries for classification, tokenization, stemming,
>   tagging, parsing, and semantic reasoning, wrappers for
>   industrial-strength NLP libraries, and an active discussion forum.
>
> Thanks to a hands-on guide introducing programming fundamentals
>   alongside topics in computational linguistics, plus comprehensive API
>   documentation, NLTK is suitable for linguists, engineers, students,
>   educators, researchers, and industry users alike. NLTK is available
>   for Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux. Best of all, NLTK is a free, open
>   source, community-driven project.

It includes taggers, stemming, corpus reading & processing, tokenizing, etc. for Russian as well as many other languages.

I would suggest reading the NLTK book available [here](http://www.nltk.org/book/).

Note that python & NLTK can be embedded in programs written in a number of other languages, can be called as a service or can run a local web server.